# media query and vuejs

Tags: css, vuejs2, media-queries

I’d like to use simple @media query **in css section of a component** but I can’t make it work.

I prepared a [codesandbox.io here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9rmv8ym7z) in the component `HelloWorld.vue`:

I would expect to change from red to green when squeezing the window…
What am I doing wrong?
[EDIT: as somebody noted, it's working in some circumstancies, it's still not working if I put this code in a component in vuejs + vuetify (while it works in a component of standard vuejs)]

```
<style>
.vega {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .vega {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance
sandro

SOLVED: it was a bogus invisible char in css selector that prevented it to be applied...

Comment: The CSS you posted seems to work perfectly well (https://jsfiddle.net/3yaj9q2m/1/); you may need to debug further.

Comment: In fact thanks. Not only it works in pure html, it works in vuejs build with vue-cli. It's probably an issue with codesandbox. But I still have the problme as it does not work in vuetify

Comment: How did you solve it? I think I have the same problem. I put the style into a raw .html file. It works fine. It just does not work in style section of Vue component.

Comment: @Mansur read the last line

Comment: @Bhumit 070 turns out it does not relevant with vue or anything else. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914416/media-query-does-not-work-in-vuejs-style-tag/59947558#59947558